# Insert row with same key after delete throws key constraint error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where we need to change an employee record to have a different ID. I've deleted the record that caused this, and intend to move the still intact record to the new ID.

However when I attempt to do the insert, I'm getting a key constraint error.

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Employee'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Employee'. The duplicate key value is (2682).

Upon reading, I understand that I'd need to rebuild indexes to accomplish this. I've done this for the non clustered indexes on the table. Does this also need to be done for the clustered indexes?

Edited to include SQL query and insert:

[image]

Comment: No, you don't need to "rebuild indexes". You have a PK violation pure and simple. Find all rows with the specified value in the primary key column. Then figure out why your query is not doing what you expect.

Comment: The record in question doesn't exist though?

select * From Employee where EEID = 2682 returns no rows

Comment: What column is the primary key actually on? And what do you mean "do the insert", you say you still have the row, so don't you want an update instead? How about you give us the actual code and sample data that you are attempting

Comment: Let me update the issue with some SQL queries and results

Comment: There ya go, I've included a screenshot for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that `SELECT` statement you're using to select the rows to be inserted (**without** any `WHERE` clause), you're inserting ***ALL*** the existing employees back into the table again.

While the first `INSERT` with `ID = 2682` will work (since the entry with `ID = 2682` has been removed before that), once SQL Server tries to insert the **second** employee fetched in the `SELECT`, also with `ID = 2682`, it will **fail ** (since there's already a new entry with that `ID`) ...

Comment: yikes, this is what I get for letting my sql get rusty